# nth child in forms using html and css not working

Tags: html

I have created a simple html code to test nth child, however it is not working for me. any value i put into the nthe child selector other than 1 wont work?

```css
.username{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.username:nth-child(n + 2){
 margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>forms</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/form.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
 <div class="username">
   <input type="text" name="First_Name" value="First Name">
      <input type="text" name="Middle_Name" value=" Middle Name">
   <input type="text" name="Last_Name" value="Last Name">
 </div>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, nth-child, looks for the "nth" element ocurrency. If you call nth-child(n+2) in your "username" div, you are looking for all ocurrencies of "username" divs equal or grater then two, that doesn't exist, you only have one ocurrency for "username", therefore, it only works if you use nth-child(1).

If you want all "input" elements, equal or grater then two, inside your "username" div, have a margin, you should do that:

```
.username input:nth-child(n+3){
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

You can put two or three more inputs inside the "username" div for more clarification, and change the value of "nth-child" for (n+1), (n+2), and (n+3), to check what happen.

Note that "nth-child" starts in "1".

```css
.username{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.username input:nth-child(n+3){
 margin-left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="username">
   <input type="text" name="First_Name" value="First Name">
   <input type="text" name="Middle_Name" value=" Middle Name">
   <input type="text" name="Last_Name" value="Last Name">
      <input type="text" name="Last_Name" value="Last Name">
      <input type="text" name="Last_Name" value="Last Name">
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing  the name of the tag to which nth-child should be applied.
.username {

```
margin-bottom: 20px;
```

}

.username input:nth-child(n + 2) {

```
background-color:red;
```

}